# Import package.* vs import package.SpecificType

Tags: java, import, overhead

Would it suppose any difference regarding overhead to write an import loading all the types within one package (`import java.*`); than just a specific type (i.e. `import java.lang.ClassLoader`)? Would the second one be a more advisable way to use than the other one?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983435/eclipse-java-is-it-harmful-to-import-java-namespace/1984499#1984499 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141144/java-import-can-be-slow

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There is not a performance or overhead cost to doing import .* vs importing specific types.  However, I consider it to be a best practice to never use import .*  My primary reason for this is I just like to keep things straightward, clean and with as little ambiguity as possible, and I think with a .* import you lose that.

Comment: Actually, I understood avoiding using import package.* as an optimization for the compiler, because it allowed the compiler to better target the class file look up when compiling the current file.

Comment: Doubt there'll be any optimization issues with this.. Except naming conflicts where you can easily avoid them using specific import statements. Even if you are too lazy to type all the imports up modern IDE's will do it for you...

Comment: Are we sure using wildcard won't be less efficient? Importing what you need should result in 1) less time to build due to less dependencies to be resolved and less artifacts to be downloaded, and 2) smaller artifact size. Am I missing something? Both of those seem like performance improvements over "import everything."

Answer (score 141):

Take a look at the java API, and you'll see many classes and interfaces with the same name in different packages.

For example:

```
java.lang.reflect.Array
java.sql.Array
```

So, if you import `java.lang.reflect.*` and `java.sql.*` you'll have a collision on the Array type, and have to fully qualify them in your code.

Importing specific classes instead will save you this hassle.

Comment: naming conflicts! I did overlooked that one. +1 to you

Comment: @Chris What is the effect of the use of `import a.b.*` on compilation time?

Comment: @saurabheights  Do we care?  No snark intended.  Compile time, is generally not a development concern unless it becomes absurd.  It's run time we're concerned with.

Answer (score 34):

This is actually a very bad problem.

Suppose you write

```
import a.*;
import b.*;
...
Foo f;
```

and class Foo exists in package a.

Now you check in your perfectly compiling code, and six months later, someone adds class Foo to package b. (Perhaps it's a third party lib that added classes in the latest version).

Poof! Now your code refuses to compile.

***Never*** use import-on-demand. It's evil!

See http://javadude.com/articles/importondemandisevil.html for more details.

RE performance:

```
import a.*;
```

vs

```
import a.X;
```

Makes no difference at runtime. The compiler hardwires the resolved class names into the generated .class files.

Comment: I was going to post a link to your article (which I read yesterday), but I thought you'd probably like to do it yourself. :)

Comment: It's not *"evil"*, it just has a downside you should be aware of.

Comment: Nope - it's an evil feature that allows breakage when code is added to external libs.

Comment: @Scott actually, other programming languages (such as C#) do just fine without importing specific classes.

Comment: "Evil" is to make such a claim without considering all the advantages and disadvantages that each choice has, and without recognizing that different developers and/or situations will give more weight to some aspects than others. To me personally, the advantages of star imports outweigh the disadvantages. so I prefer to use them.

Comment: What advantages? With today's IDEs and editors that automatically add and fold/collapse imports, I see _zero_ advantages to import-on-demand. A language feature that allows previously-working code to break when the _only_ thing that happens is a new class is added to a jar, is definitely evil.

Answer (score 17):

**Minority view:** in my code I tend to use tons of classes from a few packages along with a few odd classes here and there. I like to keep my imports list small so I can tell what is going on at a glance. To do this, I set the threshold at 4 classes. Above that, Eclipse will use * for my code. I find this keeps my package imports readable, and I tend to refer to them as the **first thing I do** when I look at a class, to answer the question: Who does it talk to?

**Regarding Name Collision:** What are the chances that you import four or more classes from two packages that have competing class names? IF it's more than 10% of the time, you might want to consider the number of packages your class relies on (e.g., refactor it into smaller classes).

Comment: I agree; I have only ever run into the AWT List vs. util List collision in practice, and then I usually just add a specific import for the one I want, which is usually the collection.

Comment: @Software Monkey, true that. The whole point of packages is that they're classes that stick together, which is the reason behind the * import.

Answer (score 12):

A good reason to never use import xxx.* is to have a clear vision of [dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276).

You can know quicker that you are using a specific class of another package because it is listed right at the beginning of the source file.

Comment: If your list of imports is 70 or 200 lines long, you no longer have a clear vision of dependencies.

Comment: But that's not the fault of the import statements, it's yours.

Comment: I think if you are using more than 3 classes of that class it is better to use .*

Answer (score 11):

After looking for further information, I came across this website where it is very well explained. [Import issue](http://java.sun.com/developer/TechTips/2000/tt0110.html#tip2) and [Does using * in an import statement affect performance?](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm031.shtml).

Is there any efficiency issue between these two styles? Possibly, but since import declarations don't actually import anything into your program, any difference is very small. Remember that there's an implicit import java.lang.* at the top of your compilation units, and java.lang in JDK 1.2.2 contains 75 classes and interfaces. An experiment using a contrived example, one with thousands of class name uses that must be looked up, showed a negligible change in compilation speed. So compilation performance should probably not be considered a factor when choosing one format over another.

There's one final angle of interest on import declarations. Suppose you use an inner class:

```
package P;

public class A {
    public static class B {}
}
```

If you want to access A from another compilation unit, you say:

```
import P.*;
```

or:
    import P.A;
But if you'd like to access B without qualification, you need to say:

```
import P.A.*;
```

or:
    import P.A.B;
The first of these makes available types within the class A found in package P. The second makes available just the type B found in class A in package P.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to use whatever the IDE default is. I find that it is not something really worth worrying about since it has no performance impact, and checking dependencies can be handled with a variety of tools.

Answer (score 5):

If you are importing more than 20 classes from the same package, you are better off using import xxx.*. "Clean Code" is in favor importing the whole package as well.

Answer (score 2):

The imports don't matter at bytecode level, so there should be no runtime difference.

I find it's best to:
a) Be explicit by listing all imports
b) Let your IDE manage it.  Any of the major IDEs can automatically update, sort, and complete your imports.

I have found a) to come in handy a couple times when doing manual repackaging outside the context of an in-IDE refactoring.  Like for instance, when marketing changes the name of your product and decides all of your packages should change name.

Answer (score 1):

It's more of a good coding practice as anyone reading your code will immediately know what classes are used by a particular class by just looking at the import block at the top of the file whereas one would have to dig to find out if you used wildcards.

Comment: No they won't; they will know all classes that were used ever - some may have been removed as the code ages.

Comment: Modern IDEs like Eclipse seem to do a good job flagging unused imports as well as showing the fully qualified class name when hovering the mouse over a class name, so I'm not sure how relevant the "have to dig" argument is. Then again, I also have my IDE "fold" the imports so they don't get in my way, so I usually don't care too much whether they are wildcard imports are specifically named classes.