# which is better in terms of perfomance?

Tags: java, import, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import package.* vs import package.SpecificType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187453/import-package-vs-import-package-specifictype)

while importing packages in java does it matter if I import all classes or is it better to use specific imports.
For example is it better to use import java.util.*
or to import the specific class of the util package which my program uses.

Comment: pls edit the question to have a more specific information on what you want to compare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes no difference at all at execution time. The compiled code will be identical - and it will also be identical to the equivalent code with *no* imports, but every type name specified in full at every point in the code.

It will almost certainly make no *significant* difference at compile time either.

Personally I use a wildcard import when writing throwaway code by hand (e.g. for samples on Stack Overflow) but get Eclipse to import specific classes when writing real code.

Comment: thanks. that perfectly answers my question