# In Java, when should I import whole packages with * instead of individual objects from the package?

Tags: java, android, import, package

Is there some disadvantage to having statements such as import android.view.* instead of just importing the objects I actually use from the view package? Will it make my compiled android application larger in size if I use the *? If yes, then what is best practice for deciding whether to import the whole package with * or just single objects ? Thanks

Comment: `Will it make my compiled android application larger in size if I use the *?` ---> NO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import package.* vs import package.SpecificType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187453/import-package-vs-import-package-specifictype)

Comment: @Sindikalis Out of curiosity: How are you learning java? It seems many "java newbies" don't understand import and I'm wondering if it's due to some "bad"/incomplete literature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In their book [Core Java Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354764), the authors state that

> The java.util.* syntax is less tedious. It has no negative effect on code size. 
>   However, if you import classes explicitly, the reader of your code knows 
>   exactly which classes you use.

The only time that you need to worry about packages is when you have a name conflict. For example, both the java.util and java.sql packages have a Date class. Now suppose you write a program that imports both packages.
    *import java.sql.** and
    *import java.util.**
If you try to use the Date class now, you will get a compile time error. You'll have to use fully qualified name if you want to use them both.

The only benefit of the import statements is convenience. It is **not** analogous to the #include directives in C.  In the book [The Java Programmin Language (It has James Gosling as one of its authors)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349806), the authors state the following,

> Import statements simply provide information (about the types you are using in your 
>   code)  to the compiler; they don't cause files to be "included" into the current file.

What I have inferred from the books *The Java Language Specification* (By Bill Joy, James Gosling et. al), and the one I mentioned above is that the import statements with the wild-cards are called *Type-Import-on-Demand Declaration*. This tells the compiler that if it finds names that it doesn't know about, it should look at package given by the *import-on-demand* statement to see if it has a member by that name.

Comment: In the old days, when you had to worry about how long it took to compile, I believe using fully qualified class name optimized the compiler time. Now with incremental compile, I think it is almost insignificant.

Answer (score 6):

You need to know that `import` isn't loading anything.  The class loader does that.

All `import` does is let you use short class names instead of long ones in your code (e.g. `Connection` instead of `java.sql.Connection`).  It will not affect the size of your Android app at all.