# When is it appropriate to import packages?

Tags: java, import

*Note: I realize that this is probably an open-ended question, so go ahead and flag for deletion if you feel this either doesn't belong or has no merit.*

I haven't been working with Java (or really programming in general) for very long and most of my time is spent on learning practical application (specifically with Android). Therefore, I realize that I am very behind when it comes to conceptual issues.

My question is this: When is it appropriate to use the `import 'package name';` statement instead of simply using the fully qualified class name?

I've seen sample code where the coder decided to use `android.widget.Button` vs. calling `import android.widget.Button` and using `Button` for every instance afterwards. I'm currently writing code where I know I will be using a certain class only once and I feel like using an `import` statement is a waste.

Any guidelines on when I should be using an `import` statement vs. using a fully qualified name would be much appreciated. I am not looking for a definitive answer, just some helpful tips.

Comment: If you use Eclipse do : "CTRL" + "SHIFT" + "O" will solve all your questions ;)

Comment: Also, this is a different question from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592951/in-java-when-should-i-import-whole-packages-with-instead-of-individual-object). I am asking using an `import` statement in general vs. using a fully qualified name (e.g. `android.view.Button btn = ...`).

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804843/java-use-import-or-explicit-package-class-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple: if you have more than 1 `Button` class (obviously, each in their own package) that you **have** to use in the **same** class, then use the fully qualified name. Otherwise, import the only `Button` class that you need.

Generally, package import is preferred as it brings cleaner code and it makes compiler knows what class (package) to compile upfront.

Comment: Does it have an effect for the JVM as well? I thought it's only syntactic sugar. Could you post a link?

Answer (score 1):

well there are three obvious reasons.

1. It makes your code short and clean.
2. If you are using many classes in a package then it does make sense to import the whole    package.
3. your import statement is sort of metadata for your classes, which declares class dependency to outer world.

Answer (score 0):

Using `import` is a matter of convenience. Using only class names in code is better for readability (and there is less characters to type, too! ;-))

Also, tools (like Eclipse) will organize imports for you and propose packages to import from based on the class name only.

As to using fully qualified class names in code - It is useful (it is a *must*, actually) if you have a *clash* on class names (For example, class `my.components.Button` and `android.widget.Button`) and you need to explicitly point in code which class you are using where. However, even in such situation, you can import one of those classes (the one used more often) and explicitly type the other.

Answer (score -2):

Always use the import, no reason not to and you get cleaner code.

Comment: elite gentleman is not answering the question that was asked. The question is not if he should use wildcards the question is if he should use import at all instead of using fully qualified names in his code.

Comment: @mbwasi, the question is `Any guidelines on when I should be using an import statement vs. using a fully qualified name would be much appreciated` and I do answer that (OP asks, **when** he/should be using an `import` statement vs. using fully qualified name).

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman ok, they way I read your answer it seemed you were talking about using wildcard or not IN the import statement itself, that's the way i understood it.

Comment: I was referring to the answer you edited by the way the one by Samir Mangroliya