# import statement declaration

Tags: java, import, compilation, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import package.* vs import package.SpecificType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187453/import-package-vs-import-package-specifictype)

I am wondering the different between java.util.* and java.util.Date in the import class declaration. Some developers prefer java.util.*, but other developers prefer declaring one specific import declaration per class. I know that this is a coding style and this is kind of trivial, but I am curious if there is any performance difference or the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance or memory allocation difference to doing import pkg.* vs. import pkg.class. But best practice to import specific package class

Comment: Is there any pros and cons? One thing that I know is that you can avoid ambiguity by specifying package class. For example, java.sql.Date and java.util.Date.  anything else besides the ambiguity?