# Import a single class in Java

Tags: java, import

Simple question but even though googled it a lot I could not find the answer.

Is it possible to import a class outside a package?

Let's say I have 2 folders `A` and `B` with a `.java` file in each, is it possible by using the clause `import` to import the class contained in `A`? `import A.Aclass` ? or it's mandatory using package syntax whenever there is the keyword `import`?

Comment: You don't even have to import it if you don't want to, you just have to use the FQCN.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: A package is basically just a folder that contains classes.  The folders `A` and `B` *are* packages in your example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import package.\* vs import package.SpecificType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187453/import-package-vs-import-package-specifictype)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to import the class with the import statement. For better understanding let's assume that you have three folders `foldera`, `folderb` and `folderc` where `foldera` contains a  .java file named "`ClassA.java`", `folderb` contains another .java file named "`ClassB.java`" and `folderc` contains a .java file named "`ClassC.java`". Now, if you want to uses the member data and operations of "`ClassA.java`" in "`ClassC.java`" you can use the `import` statement as shown below:

```
import foldera.ClassA
```

If you want to use the member data & operations of "ClassB.java" in "ClassC.java" it is also possible with the import statement

```
import folderb.ClassB
```

As per the java source file declaration rule, if the class is a part of a package, the `package` statement must be the first line in the source code file, before any `import` statements that may be present. In this example, the first line of `"ClassC.java"` source file must be `package folderc` since it is located in `folderc`. Similarly, the first line of `"ClassA.java"` source file must be `package foldera`, and the first line of `"ClassB.java"` source file must be `package folderb`.

Hope now you are clear with the concept!
Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the class is defined to have a `package a;` then you need to import the class with the package name. If you have two packages which contain a class with the same name, then in your class which needs to invoke each of them, you will need to use a fully-qualified name. For example:

```
import a.Foo;
import b.Foo;

public class Bar
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        a.Foo aFoo = new a.Foo();
        b.Foo bFoo = new b.Foo();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you have two packages with classes of the same name, you can simply skip importing them, but rather -- using them by their fully-qualified names (FQN-s).

If the class does not have a `package ...;`, then simply import it as:

```
import Foo;
```

However, if you have two packages (from different libraries) which contain classes with identical FQN-s, then the first one on the classpath will be picked.

Please, bear in mind that the convention for naming packages is to use lowercase letters and for classes -- the name should start with an upper case letter for each word in the class' name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

If you have the following:

Package: PackA

Class: ClasA

Do:

import PackA.ClassA; //Import the class

OR

import PackA.*; //Import all the classes within the package

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use package syntax.

- importing all class inside folder `A`.

  ```
  import com.pack.A.*;
  ```
- importing specific class inside folder `A`.

  ```
  import com.pack.ClassName;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible just import the package

syntax

```
import pck.ClassA or import pck.*
```