# Why do I have to import java.awt.* AND java.awt.event.* (for example)

Tags: java, swing, import, awt

In an exercise program I'm working on right now, it calls for a handful of imports, like so:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;
import java.net.URL;
```

ELI5: My question (I'm slightly past the newbie beginner tutorials, and getting into intermediate? now.) is just as the title suggests. Am I actually required to import java.awt.event.* if I've already covered it with java.awt.*?

If not, why is this the seeming convention?

Comment: *"Am I actually required to `import java.awt.event.*` if I've already covered it with `java.awt.*`?"* - Yes, you are required to do this.  A import will only import the specified class (`javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener`) or classes in the specified package (`javax.swing.*`), it will not import the sub packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An import statement ending in an asterisk only imports all *classes* from that package, not any subpackages. So if you have class A living in com.example, and class B living in com.example.subtype, an import statement like

```
import com.example.*;
```

will import class A but not class B. In order to import class B you'd have to add

```
import com.example.subtype.*;
```

This is to ensure that if you need a number of classes from a 'higher' package (hierarchically speaking), you don't import all classes from every subpackage beneath it which you might not need or want, some of which could have the same name leading to classname conflicts.

ie, if there is a class `com.example.subtype.Type` and a class `com.example.order.Type` you don't want an import statement like `import com.example.*;` to import both Types.

This is also why it is generally better to explicitly import certain classes instead of all classes from a package (as you do with the asterisk), unless you need so many classes from that package the load of imports will only serve to confuse.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use .*

For Example, you only want to use an JFrame, you can import

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

but why import all functions of the package (not subpackages), if you only need one?

Better use this (in this Example):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

See also here: [Import package.* vs import package.SpecificType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187453/import-package-vs-import-package-specifictype?lq=1)