# Find dead class in Java with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new ( and only person ) on old Java project. Couple guys have developed this before me. Is there any tool ( plugin for Eclipse would be nice ) which can find in project dead classes ( classes that are declared but they don't use anymore anywhere ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find unused classes in a Java Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665563/find-unused-classes-in-a-java-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ has a "Find Usages" that you can apply to classes, methods, strings - anything.  Perhaps the Eclipse help can turn up such a thing.

Or maybe you should switch to IntelliJ.

IntelliJ can also generate UML that includes dependencies.  Any class or package without a dependency would be a good candidate for removal.  You'd get a quick visual that way.

Comment: For "Find Usages" won't the user have to go to each individual class and check for it? Can it applied to a complete workspace to point out all unused classes?

Comment: Individual classes, as far as I know.

Comment: it sounds like, he is looking for a complete list of 'dead' classes. if not the default shortcut in eclipse is shift+ctrl+g

Comment: I'll have to see if IntelliJ has something similar.

Comment: If you mean something where you select a single identifier and find references to it throughout the project, Eclipse has that (Search -> References).  Sounds like the OP wants something that will do this automatically for all classes, rather than manually invoking it on each.

Comment: @Dave Costa Yes, that is what I want. I am lazy programmer. I accept plugin for Netbeans, just not to work manually !

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Emma](http://www.eclemma.org/installation.html) plugin to determine code coverage and look for the classes with 0% coverage after a full run.

To make sure before you remove classes, use the eclipse function that shows all references to the class in case it is used in exception handling.

Comment: When I run this plugin, it seems to me like plugin just analyzed classes on which I used during the running application ( if I have tabs  and I don't open them it seems like coverage 0% ) . Is this true I am wrong ?

Comment: @Damir, That is correct, emma gives an overview of code that ran during a session. You can use emma to check code coverage of test sets, or in your case code coverage for a "normal" run in which you try to use all functionality in one session.

Comment: I've only thought of Emma for test code coverage.  This is an interesting idea, thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like similar question already asked on Stackoverfow check out the following links already asked on SO

- [How to find unused/dead code in java projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162551/how-to-find-unused-dead-code-in-java-projects)
- [Find unused classes in a Java Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665563/find-unused-classes-in-a-java-eclipse-project)

Check out the answers

Answer (score 2):

http://eclipsenuggets.blogspot.com/2007/05/here-is-quick-way-to-eliminate-dead.html

This worked for me (although I tried it several years ago)