# Does UCDetector work for android projects?

Tags: android, eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-plugin

I've got an android project that I started from an old standard Java project, so because of the vast difference in target platform, I have a lot of dead code to cleanup.

I've seen [UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/) [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665563/find-unused-classes-in-a-java-eclipse-project) for [finding unused public methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162551/how-to-find-unused-dead-code-in-java-projects) in java projects in Eclipse.  I installed it as directed, and it just doesn't show up on the menu, and I have no idea how to get it to work.

**Has anyone got this combo to work, or have another recommendation?  Or know how to get it to show up?**

[image: My menu, where is it?]

(I've tried [Find Bugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) which found some good stuff, but it doesn't find unused public code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, UCDetector works for android projects. I just installed it and it works.

It's available in context menu of project in Package Explorer.

Comment: I posted my menu... it's not there.  Find Bugs shows up.  I'm confused.  I just dropped version 1.8.0 in dropins directory like it says.

Comment: Try to remove it from dropins and install from http://ucdetector.sourceforge.net/update

Comment: Aha! I had to do both, put it in dropins and then install from the update site.

Answer (score 2):

Big warning!

It might partially work, but beware, cause it doesn't seem to know about XML-defined callback functions.

If you have installed a callback function on a widget, say a button in an XML Style Sheet, and it is not called in code, UCdetector will think it has 0 references, and suggest it deleted. This obviously is wrong, and will render your code uncompilable.

There might be other similar issues, related to Android specifics.

Viggo

Comment: +1, but it's not a really "big warning", in my opinion. Just operate mindfully and you'll see it's a great companion.