# View classes dependency graph plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-3.4

Is there any plugins I can use for Eclipse that will show graphical view of classes dependencies?

Comment: use or not use maven is not relating to generating dependency graph using eclipse. i just wanna show view of how each java files related to another

Comment: Not an eclipse plugin, but if external tools are interesting as well you might want to watch degraph https://github.com/schauder/degraph (disclaimer I am the author)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[Classycle](http://classycleplugin.graf-tec.ch/index.html)** can be a good start (for static dependencies between classes at least)

(I find their graph a bit complicated to follow though : [CDA - Class Dependency Analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276/java-package-cycle-detection-how-to-find-the-specific-classes-involved/71610#71610) is an external tool, but produce much more readable dependency graphs)

Comment: CDA can only analyse same packages .classes?    cant analyse different packages .classes/java files?

Comment: CDA can analyze any package you want.

Comment: ya. class diagram solved. how about sequence diagram...etc.  ?

Comment: It won't install for me on Eclipse Mars.1 :(

Comment: @mrswadge that is too bad, although more than 6 years later, that can happen.

Answer (score 8):

[stan4j](http://stan4j.com/):

- Free for private use
- For commercial use requires license
- Video on homepage does a good job of demoing features

Answer (score 5):

For a more in-depth analysis, check out [nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/).

Comment: I sure like your product (+1) but haven't fully evaluated it yet for my work (since it is not freeware)

Comment: Site is down in 2019.  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nwire-java-code-exploration-visualization is this the correct tool ?

Answer (score 2):

I find ispace => http://ispace.stribor.de/ ideal for showing circular dependencies etc. Tip: do a project clean after every major refactor to get it to update the graphs.

Comment: It says: The site is broken.

Please go to web.archive.org for the snapshot: http://web.archive.org/web/20111203070026/http://ispace.stribor.de/index.php