# Generate a map/chart of a project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, workflow

In Eclipse, is there a way to generate some kind of "project map" or flowchart that shows what classes are referenced and where within the workspace?

In other words, is there a way to visually represent the call hierarchy of a workspace or project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any given method, you can right-click, "Open Call Hierarchy" and look upward or downward.
For any given method or class, you can right-click, "References".

There's nothing to show a full graph of references.  In many/most cases, this would be too cluttered to be useful, IMHO.

For plugins, see [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005479/eclipse-view-classes-dependency-graph-plugin).

Comment: I used Classycle from one of the answers in your linked post. It isn't visual, but it serves the purpose of knowing what classes are used by what.