# View Package Dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way to **view package dependencies** in Eclipse? I seem to remember a long time ago that it was possible. I have a *packageX* and want to see what packages refer to it. Ie *packageY* references it, but not *packageZ*.

There seem to be some outdated plugins out there, for example Java Dependency Viewer, but the comments for the plugin say 'don't bother'.

Comment: https://sevalapsha.wordpress.com/2008/02/01/java-code-structure-and-dependencies-analysis-tools-for-eclipse/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005479/eclipse-view-classes-dependency-graph-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean a *java package*, there is a possibility: You right-click the package in the project explorer, select References → Workspace and get ... a list of almost no results.

Then you go into the search menu (the small triangle ▿ at the top right border of the search view), select "filters" and uncheck the "imports" box. Then all references to your package within your workspace should appear in the view.